# File compression server can only compress one file without being restarted

Tags: java, sockets, networking, compression, fileoutputstream

I've been debugging this for a few days and I can't seem to find what is wrong. This code is for a server that receives UDP packets and then compresses the bytes to create a zip file and an unzipped file. The problem is that it seemingly works for the first file that is sent, but needs to be restarted for any other file. I'm guessing I am closing something wrong, but I can't seem to find it.

```
for (;;) {  // Run forever, receiving and echoing datagrams
        socket.receive(packet);
        byte[] data = packet.getData();
        String fileName = new String(data, 0, packet.getLength(),"US-ASCII");

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName.trim()); //unzipped file output
        FileOutputStream fout2 = new FileOutputStream(fileName.trim() + ".zip"); //zipped file output
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout2); //I guess this writes zip bytes to fout2?

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName.trim()); //call the entry in the zip file "proj3.bin"
        zout.putNextEntry(entry); //the next entry our ZipOutputStream is going to write is "proj3.bin"

        while(true) {
            socket.receive(packet);
            data = packet.getData();
            String magicString = new String(data, 0, packet.getLength(), "US-ASCII");
            int index = magicString.indexOf("--------MagicStringCSE283Miami");
            if(index != -1){
                fout.write(data, 0, index);
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();

                zout.write(data, 0, index); //write the byteBuffer's data to the client via the zip output stream
                zout.flush(); //push all data out of the zipOutputStream before continuing
                fout2.flush();
                zout.close();
                fout2.close();
                break;
            }
            //System.out.println("packet received");
            fout.write(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            fout.flush();

            zout.write(data, 0, packet.getLength()); //write the byteBuffer's data to the client via the zip output stream
            zout.flush(); //push all data out of the zipOutputStream before continuing
            fout2.flush();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You create the output streams before entering the infinite loop (`while(true)`). Inside that loop you close those streams, but you never create them again.

I guess, simply moving the lines that create the streams inside the loop will resolve your issue. But take care of the file names.